# Won an argument my instructor today regarding this but is it correct?

Tags: c++

The discussion was about whether or not some dynamically allocated variable within a function (other than main) can be returned by reference.

Where we applied this was different, but just to illustrate the point, I'll consider returning a simple int as follows:

```
int& myFunc() {
     unique_ptr<int> p(make_unique<int>(10)); 
     int& r = (*p);    // A reference to the value in heap pointed by p.
     return r;
}
```

Now, even though the pointer handle is lost after going out of scope, we still have another handle (which is the reference variable r) to still access the dynamically allocated int with a value 10.

My instructor was like it may give a compilation error but when I compiled and ran the code, it worked fine.

So, is this allowed or is it dangerous in any way?

Comment: You're not returning any reference there and you **are** indeed leaking memory.

Comment: You're returning a copy and then leaking memory, so it is indeed dangerous, but allowed.

Comment: Woah, wait. What do you mean I'm not returning any reference?

Comment: @Bazooka, if you wanted to return a reference, the function signature would be `int&`, not `int`

Comment: Oh man, my bad. That was what I did in the class. Just edited to fix it. Typo. Really sorry. Is it fine now?

Comment: My bad. My bad. How in the world did I miss it. That was the whole point. Sorry.

Comment: Is it safe to do what I did, now?

Comment: @Bazooka, even if you changed the function to return `int&`, you'd still likely leak memory, because people don't expect that a `int&` returned from a function was allocated with `new`, so they won't call `delete (&returned_int)` Edit: However, it is indeed legal. A bit obscene, but legal in C++

Comment: @AndyG: Fair point mate. How about I use a smart (unique) pointer. How about now?

Comment: @Bazooka depends on what type of smart pointer you're using :)

Comment: @Bazooka, unless you're returning the unique pointer, it will go out of scope at the end of your function and delete its allocated memory, meaning accessing the address of the returned `int` will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Please stop editing the question. The answer keeps changing depending on your edits, because you keep changing the question!

Comment: @Bazooka, Sorry, but as it stands, what you have will definitely result in undefined behavior. In fact, really only the first post you had would have resulted in a well behaving function from an API standpoint. The second edit would have likely resulted in a memory leak.

Comment: @AndyG: Will the `delete (&returned_int);` statement mentioned by you take care of deallocating the memory safely?

Comment: With the second version of the code you had (before the `unique_ptr` edit), yes.

Comment: Thank you AndyG. If I may trouble with just one last thing, how do we dereference a unique pointer? I thought it was just as normal pointers using the '*' prefix.

Comment: @Bazooka. yep `std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(2);
 std::cout << *p << std::endl;`

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate.

Answer (score 8):

Version 1 of your question used this code:

```
int myFunc() {
     int* p = new int(10);
     int& r = (*p);    // A reference to the value in heap pointed by p.
     return r;
}
```

That's returning an `int` by value, not by reference. The value is copied, the reference is lost, and the allocated memory is leaked. Technically, that's all legal, but leaking memory is bad (and you'd never be able to free the allocated memory).

---

Version 2 of your question used this code:

```
int& myFunc() {
     int* p = new int(10);
     int& r = (*p);    // A reference to the value in heap pointed by p.
     return r;
}
```

That's legal as well. It returns a reference to the allocated object. The object outlives the function call, and the reference is still valid. You will need to capture the object by reference and delete it (don't forget to take its address!) to avoid a memory leak, but the behavior of that is valid.

A safe way to use this code is as follows:

```
int& ref = myFunc();
std::cout << ref << std::endl;
// Free the memory:
delete (&ref);
```

---

Version 3 of your question used this code:

```
int& myFunc() {
     unique_ptr<int> p(make_unique<int>(10)); 
     int& r = (*p);    // A reference to the value in heap pointed by p.
     return r;
}
```

That's not valid. The `unique_ptr p` will delete its object at the end of the function call, and the function will return an invalid, dangling reference. That's one of many ways to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndyG: "The compiler won't complain" is not the same as "not illegal". Fortunately, the standard does not use such ambiguous terms. This is indeed UB rather than being _ill-formed_ code.

Comment: @AndyG: No such compiler can exist within our physical reality. 50% of what a compiler does is outside of the standard. That's the whole point of it! To bridge the gap between a C++ program and an Assembly program for your computer.

Comment: Updated to more carefully tread the C++ minefield of technical terms :)

Comment: The third case highlights a new point. Lots of new things learned today. :)

Comment: Good! I'm glad it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

A compilation error isn't necessarily expected, but what you're doing is invalid, as it causes the caller to have undefined behaviour if it ever uses the returned reference.

Most modern compilers can be configured to give warnings for functions that return a reference to a local variable.   No compilers do this out of the box, however, so you need to read your compiler documentation (and/or documentation for your development environment) to work out how.

However, since your code is masking what it is doing behind a `unique_pointer` (coupled with use of dynamic memory allocation) it is quite possible that a compiler cannot (and, if it can, may not anyway) emit any diagnostic for your code.   `unique_pointer` is a template class, and template instantiation is a complex process that potentially makes it more difficult for a compiler to issue diagnostics in cases like this.

In the end, you have both won and lost your argument with your instructor.

- You have won in the sense that a compiler is not required to emit a diagnostic given your code.
- You have lost in the sense that lack of a compilation error does not mean your function is correct or valid.  Specifically, your code will cause any caller that uses the returned reference to have undefined behaviour.